# Unable to download Excel file when call from Postman

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to download Excel file using web API but I am unable to download file in postman where as I am able to download Excel file when I enter URL in browser though while opening file I get warning message like below :

[image]

[image]

[image]

When i hit endpoint using POSTMAN then file get corrupted and it is showing junk characters.

Code :

```
protected virtual byte[] ExportToXlsx<T>(IEnumerable<T> itemsToExport)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var xlPackage = new ExcelPackage())
                {
                    // get handles to the worksheets
                    var worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(typeof(T).Name);

                    //create Headers and format them 
                    var manager = new PropertyManager<T>(itemsToExport.First());
                    manager.WriteCaption(worksheet, SetCaptionStyle);

                    var row = 2;

                    foreach (var items in itemsToExport)
                    {
                        manager.CurrentObject = items;
                        manager.WriteToXlsx(worksheet, row++, false);
                    }

                    xlPackage.Save();
                }
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }



private readonly IServiceContext ctx;
public void Download(string guid)
{
   var bytes = ExportToXlsx(list);
   ctx.reqobj.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"demo.xlsx\"");
   ctx.reqobj.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
   ctx.reqobj.HttpContext.Response.Body.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Note : I am using `OfficeOpenXml` for Excel file creation.

I will appreciate any help.

**Update :** 
[image]

Comment: The xlsx format uses compression which is why the output appears to show junk characters, it's not corrupted.

Comment: @MarkG So is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you're returning `byte[]` instead of `IActionResult` and returning [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult)?

Comment: @MarkG I am using asp.net core web api in which i am only having IServiceContext

Comment: I don't think that is a restriction unless I'm missing something.  See [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types).

Comment: @MarkG Yes but we have a wrapper in which we only work with IServiceContext object.But i am not getting that when i enter url in browser then file download successfully but in case of postman i am getting junk characters.See my update

Comment: I repeat, the "junk" characters you're seeing are an artifact of compression.  If you unzip the downloaded file you will see XML.  The fact that Excel isn't able to read the file means that it must be malformed.

Comment: @User How is the memory stream related to the excel package? there are some inconsistencies in the information provided. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to confirm the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi:I posted my whole code.I have taken code from here :https://www.nopcommerce.com/downloads.aspx. Only thing is i am using web api core.If you can tell me what i can provide more so i will update my question accordingly.Thanks for your valuable time

Comment: @Nkosi I updated my question with some changes in code

Answer (score 5):

Try using "Send and download" instead of "Send"

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/responses

Answer (score 2):

The stream needs to be passed to the package.

Right now nothing is being given to the package,

```
//...

using (var xlPackage = new ExcelPackage())

//...
```

So nothing is being saved to the stream, which is why the error is shown when trying to open the file.

There is no need to convert the memory stream to an array. Return the stream and pass that along for the response.

```
protected virtual Stream ExportToXlsx<T>(IEnumerable<T> itemsToExport) {
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream)) { //<<< pass stream
        // get handles to the worksheets
        var worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(typeof(T).Name);
        //create Headers and format them 
        var manager = new PropertyManager<T>(itemsToExport.First());
        manager.WriteCaption(worksheet, SetCaptionStyle);
        var row = 2;
        foreach (var items in itemsToExport) {
            manager.CurrentObject = items;
            manager.WriteToXlsx(worksheet, row++, false);
        }
        xlPackage.Save();
    }
    return stream;
}
```

A controller action to return the file would look like this

```
public IActionResult Download(string guid) {

    //...get list

    var file = ExportToXlsx(list);
    var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats";
    var fileName = "demo.xlsx";

    return File(file, contentType, fileName); //returns a FileStreamResult
}
```

It was indicated in comments that the above is done in a support method.

Using the same approach

```
private readonly IServiceContext ctx;

//...

public void Download(string guid) {

    //...get list

    using(var fileStream = ExportToXlsx(list)) {
        if (fileStream.CanSeek && fileStream.Position != 0) {
            fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats";
        var fileName = "demo.xlsx";
        var response = ctx.reqobj.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{fileName}\"");
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", fileStream.Length.ToString());
        response.ContentType = contentType;
        fileStream.CopyTo(response.Body);
    }
}
```

the generated file is copied over to the body of the response.

As for postman, the tool is simply showing the content return in the response. It does not try to download the actual file as an attachment.

Comment: I tried with the changes you mentioned but still getting junk characters when trying in postman.Moreover when i hit url in browser excel still gives warning message.I think this OpenOfficeXml seems ti be incompatible with asp.net webapi core

Comment: We have a wrapper in which we only work with IServiceContext object so i cant use this ActionResult.

Comment: @User you say you are hitting an endpoint. Show the endpoint code. The `Download` suggested in the answer is meant to be the controller action.

Comment: Yes i am hitting an endpoint and Download is my supporting method which gets hit thought middleware and i am getting httpcontext in IserviceContext object

Answer (score 2):

Postman doesn't download any file just return you the data that the server or your service provides. i have a project that download an excel to with the OpenXML here is an example with which you can guide with some styles to.

```
[HttpGet]
    public void DownloadTable(int id)
    {
        List<Employee> all = db.Employees.Where(x => x.ManagerId == id).ToList();
        String file = "Example.xlsx";
        String path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), file);
        List<string[]> headerRow = new List<string[]>() { new string[] { "EmployeeId", "Name", "Shift", "Timestamp" } };
        string headerRange = "A2:" + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(headerRow[0].Length + 64) + "2";
        ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
        excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Employees");
        var page = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Employees"];
        page.Cells["A1:D1"].Merge = true;
        page.Cells["A1:D1"].Value = "Supervisor: " + all.FirstOrDefault().Manager + " - " + id;
        page.Cells["A1:D1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        page.Cells[headerRange].LoadFromArrays(headerRow);

        int z = 3;
        foreach (Reporte r in all)
        {
            page.Cells["A" + z].Value = r.Id;
            page.Cells["B" + z].Value = r.Name;
            page.Cells["C" + z].Value = r.Shift;
            page.Cells["D" + z].Value = r.Timestamp;
            z++;
        }

        page.Cells["D3:D" + z].Style.Numberformat.Format = "dddd dd MMMM YYYY";
        page.Cells["A2:D2"].AutoFilter = true;

        page.Cells["A1:D" + z].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
        page.Cells["A1:D" + z].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
        page.Cells["A2:D" + z].AutoFitColumns();
        page.Cells["A1:D1"].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        page.Cells["A1:D1"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(1, 183, 222, 232));
        FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(path);
        excel.SaveAs(excelFile);

        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                           "attachment; filename=" + file + ";");
        response.TransmitFile(path);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
        File.Delete(path);
    }
```